# Kotlin: How to create a generic decorator class using a delagate

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, delegates, decorator

I was looking for a way to timestamp arbitrary data using a decorator function. However the following is not valid kotlin code

```
data class Timestamped<T: Any>(val timestamp: Instant, private val decorated: T): T by decorated
```

The goal is to add a timestamp property to the data while still having its member properties directly accessible ie

```
val timedString = Timestamped(Instant.now(), "Hello World")
println(timedString.timestamp)
println(timedString.substring(1))
```

Comment: This is not possible. That would require a separate type per each `T`, but we have only one type here: `Timestamped`.

Comment: Then what is the closest behavior possible. I have used similar patterns in C++. Could it be done using annotations?

Comment: maybe you need [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html)?

Comment: Closest behavior possible is to make `decorated` public (probably rename it) and then access it directly: `timedString.decorated.substring(1)`. At least I don't see any other option, other than code generation.